# trying to perform specific operation on specific number in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this question:

> Write a Python code to accept five number from the user to create a List. Traverse the list
> and print double the value of even numbers and triple the value of odd numbers.

I was successful appending the numbers to the right indexes but my if and for loops are screwing me over.

My code (doesn't work well):

```
num1 = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter Number 2: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter Number 3: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter Number 4: "))
num5 = int(input("Enter Number 5: "))

num_list = []
num_list.append(num1)
num_list.append(num2)
num_list.append(num3)
num_list.append(num4)
num_list.append(num5)

for i in num_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        i *= 2
        num_list.append(i)
    else:
        i *= 3
        num_list.append(i)
print(num_list)
```

Comment: Hint: you are appending to a list you are iterating over. Will the iteration ever stop?

Comment: that seems to be the problem. idk how to solve it

Comment: Your assignment does not say anything about appending when you traverse the list, it says to *print*.

Comment: why are you appending the calculated value? just print

Comment: so, I should append those numbers to an empty list

Comment: No, read your assignment again. It does not say anything about putting the computed values into any list.

Comment: YAY.... the solution was to just add the numbers to a new empty list. at least I wasn't being an absolute smooth brain. at least I don't think

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment requires you to print the computed values. Currently you are appending to the list you are iterating over, resulting in an infinite loop.

Change `num_list.append(i)` to `print(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Traverse the list and print double the value of even numbers and triple the value of odd numbers.

You can literally translate this English sentence to Python:

```
for i in num_list:     # traverse the list
    if i % 0 == 0:
        print(2 * i)   # print double the value of even numbers
    else:
        print(3 * i)   # print triple the value of odd numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = 0 # initiate the while iteration var to stop the while loop`
num_list = [] # initiate empty list to append the input from user

while x < 5:`
    numb = int(input("enter a number:")) # input var
    num_list.append(numb)
    x += 1 # increment to ensure the while loop doesn't go on infinitely

    print(num_list) # print this to ensure the first block did as required

for i in num_list:
        if i % 2==0: # first if statement for even numbers`
            `print(i*2)  #you can change to append however your problem said print
`        elif i % 2 != 0: # check for odd numbers in the list
            print(i * 3)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take input five times into a list, why in the world are you creating five variables first ? Just append directly. Then iterate over that list and print doubles and triples:

```py
inlist = []
for i in range(5): # how many times the user should be asked for input
    instr = input("Enter number: ") # take input 
    innum = int(instr) # convert to number
    inlist.append(innum)

for num in inlist:
    if num % 2 == 0: # even
        print(num * 2)
    else: # odd
        print(num * 3)
```

If you want it shorter:

```py
inlist = []
for i in range(5): # how many times the user should be asked for input
    instr = inlist.append(int(input("Enter number: "))) 

for num in inlist:
    if num % 2 == 0: # even
        print(num * 2)
    else: # odd
        print(num * 3)
```

---

#### This is not suitable for your assignment, only for yourself

That's how one would do it in a real application:

```py
inlist = [int(input("Enter number: ")) for i in range(5)]

for num in inlist:
    print(num * [2, 3][num % 2])
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the input. I never thought of using for loops
I didn't think it was valid to do it so thank u for explaining it well

Answer (score 0):

The answer I landed on:-

```
num1 = int(input("Enter Number 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter Number 2: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter Number 3: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter Number 4: "))
num5 = int(input("Enter Number 5: "))

num_list = []
num_list.append(num1)
num_list.append(num2)
num_list.append(num3)
num_list.append(num4)
num_list.append(num5)

emptylist = []
for i in num_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        i *= 2
        emptylist.append(i)
    else:
        i *= 3
        emptylist.append(i)
print(emptylist)
```

The answer I should have used:-

```
inlist = []
for i in range(5): # how many times the user should be asked for input
    instr = input("Enter number: ") # take input 
    innum = int(instr) # convert to number
    inlist.append(innum)

for num in inlist:
    if num % 2 == 0: # even
        print(num * 2)
    else: # odd
        print(num * 3)
```

the one I should have used gives the correct number but not in the way I wanted it to (in list form). u could probable append those number to an empty list to fix that. thank u everyone for the help